# firebase function query string value lost character

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a token key with value:

```
{token:e6nwnpyw7bw:APA91bHdmjlQvLH2JMYn_xYxWvEvMd-6n81UZ1odcG1sDFNfIAlZY-CRHGZSqf85pZUT4aOoxGCqB6X50oCGdKLcugRjNW_AbUCGptyRajC5UYDohPjI3L05VM0TkVRLLhKSiChdpNY-}
```

This was stored in firebase database correct.

But when I query this token from firebase functions I got:

`e6nwnpyw7bw:APA91bHdmjlQvLH2JMYn_xYxWvEvMd-6n81UZ1odcG1sDFNfIAlZY-CRHGZSqf85pZUT4aOoxGCqB6X50oCGdKLcugRjNW_AbUCGptyRajC5UYDohPjI3L05VM0TkVRLLhKSiChdpNY`

The last character "`-`" was lost. Not sure what's the reason? Any help, thanks!

**EDIT** 
I logged the token in this way:

```
console.log("[" + token + "]")
```

for other token without "-" at the end it works correct.

Comment: where did you get the token, in console.log?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes, I use console.log and checked from firebase function logs page.

Comment: The Firebase Database doesn't automatically modify your data. Please show the code of how you get the token, write it to the database, read it, and print it.